# Angular BehaviorSubject usage in service and component, possible race condition

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm sure this is an easy problem, I just don't know where to pinpoint it.
I have an UserProfile service that creates a BehaviorSubject for the userdata.
When I log in I use this service to broadcast the userdata.
Once logged in I subscribe to this userdata in my Dashbord component. But the userdata observable is only returning the first empty object when I first created the BehaviorSubject. It is as if the login function that pushes the new data with .next() is only running after the dashboard subscribed to the BehaviourSubject. I tried putting the subscribe of my dashboard in ngAfterContentInit() so that the .next() runs before the subscription, but I'm still getting a blank object. If I run a .next() via set_new_data() function within my dashbord to check if the observable work, I get the data passed by .next(); But I don't get the data my login-component set via the set_userdata() function within my service.

Can we not share data like this using a service? Is the service destroyed after leaving the login component or what is happening?

My USerProfile Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserProfileService {
    public isLoggedIn: boolean = false;
    public userdata: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});

    constructor() {

    }

    public set_userdata(data) {
        // this.userdata = data;
        console.log(this.userdata);
        if (this.userdata === undefined) {
            console.log(data);
            //this.userdata = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>(data);
            console.log(this.userdata);
        } else {
            console.log(this.userdata);
            this.userdata.next(data);
        }

    }
}
```

My Dashbord Component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard',
    styleUrls: ['./dashboard.scss'],
    templateUrl: './dashboard.html'
})
export class Dashboard {
    public isLoggedIn: boolean;
    public curr_user: object;

    constructor(private _appGlobals: AppGlobals, private _user: UserProfileService) {
        this._appGlobals.isUserLoggedIn.subscribe(value => this.isLoggedIn = value);
        // this.curr_user = _user.userdata;
    }

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        console.log("this executes first");
        this._user.userdata.subscribe(value => {
            this.curr_user = value;
            console.log(value);
        });
    }

    set_new_data() {
        let obj = {
            name: "test",
            age: 45
        };
        this._user.userdata.next(obj);
    }
}
```

My Console output, (shows empty object: {}, expected the userdata)

[image]

Comment: Where do you provide `UserProfileService`? Why do you have this line commented out in you code `//this.userdata = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>(data);`. It's safe to remove it completely. There shouldn't be any need to assign a new instance to it. This would invalidate all subscriptions.

Comment: I provide for it in the LoginModule and the DashbordModule. That commented line was because I was trying to get the initial instance to have the correct data when creating the BSubject

Comment: Is one of these modules lazy-loaded? To initialize the BehaviorSubject, just call `this._userdata.next(someInitialValue);`

Comment: I think it is lazy loaded, I am working on the https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin framework. for the login path i have this decleration: `loadChildren: 'app/pages/login/login.module#LoginModule'`

Comment: Lazy-loaded modules create their own DI root scope. It's likely that there are 2 instances of your `UserProfileService` around. Try to **only** provide the service in `AppModule` and try again if you get the desired behavior. You can implement `forRoot()` and use `forRoot()` to import lazy loaded modules to ensure only a single service instance is created. https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-is-the-forroot-method

Comment: Thank you Gunter that solved my problem, I moved the provider decleration to AppModule and now it is working as expected. Please can you move your comment to an answer so I may give you the points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that you have only a single instance of your service, otherwise the subscriber might subscribe to a different `BehaviorSubject` than the one you use to emit the events with.

Providing a service on a component can result in as many service instances as instances of this component are created.

Another pitfall that can cause multiple instances are lazy-loaded modules which get their own DI root scope.
Providers from non-lazy-loaded modules are hoisted to the application-root scope, and even when multiple non-lazy-loaded modules providing the same service, there will be only a single instance.

Because DI scopes can't be updated after initialization, it's not possible to hoist providers from lazy-loaded modules into the application root scope, therefore a new "root" scope is created (as a child scope of the application root scope or another lazy-loaded "root" scope) for each set of lazy-loaded modules that are loaded together.

Using `forRoot` allows to add providers to the application root scope from lazy-loaded modules. See also https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-is-the-forroot-method,
or alternatively just provide the service in `AppModule` or any other module that is known to not be lazy-loaded directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you return `userdata` from `set_userdata(data)` as an Observable and then subscribe to that function instead of the `Subject` itself your code should work as expected. Although I am not sure about best practice;

```
//UserProfileService
public set_userdata(data) { //--> Maybe make this get_userdata()
    // this.userdata = data;
    console.log(this.userdata);
    if (this.userdata === undefined) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(this.userdata);
    } else {
        console.log(this.userdata);
        this.userdata.next(data);
    }
    return this.userdata.asObservable();
}

//Dashboard
ngAfterContentInit() { //--> this could be in ngOnInit
    console.log("this executes first");
    this._user.set_userdata().subscribe(value => {
        this.curr_user = value;
        console.log(value);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response, I added:   `public get_userdata() {
        return this.userdata.asObservable();
    }` in my userProfile service, still using the set_userdata for my login to update the data. But still getting empty object on my dashboard: `this._user.get_userdata().subscribe(value => {
            this.curr_user = value;
            console.log(value);
        });`